# Spring mvc and jquery produces 415 error

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I have following jquery

```
<script>
var response = '';
$.ajax({ type: "POST",   
     url: "http://localhost:8080/hsv06/checkUserExists",   
     async: false,
     data: "title=foo",
     success : function(text)
     {
         response = text;
     }
});

console.log(response);
</script>
```

And here is the rest controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/checkUserExists", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody boolean checkUser(@RequestBody Object title){
    System.out.println(title);
    return true;        
}
```

However this produces the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/hsv06/checkUserExists 415 (Unsupported Media Type)
 send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ (index):57
```

What is the problem? What is wrong with the way I am sending the data?

Answer (score 0):

415 means unsupported media type. Your server consumes application/json, so you client must provide application/json data. To fix it, just add the type to your jquery like the following.

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",   
     url: "http://localhost:8080/hsv06/checkUserExists",   
     async: false,
     data: JSON.stringify({title: "food"}),
     // specifying data type
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success : function(text)
     {
         response = text;
     }
});
```

> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
>   charset=UTF-8')
>
> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

Your Spring REST backend should be like the following. Since the post data is {title: "food"}, Spring will parse it into a Map.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/checkUserExists", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody boolean checkUser(@RequestBody Map<String, String> param){
    System.out.println(param);
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: ok, your data should be in json format. but in your code, it is data: "title=foo", which is not. what do you wanna post actually?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it out. based on the assumption that you want to post the string "title=foo".

Comment: yes i want to post json, i applied your changes but still same error persists

Comment: still, I am suspecting the data type. you can try {title: foo}. I've updated it, you can try the code out. I've tested locally

Comment: still same error, can you post your jquery and controller, i put a comma after "utf-8" on the your jquery

Comment: odd please share your project with me. wongzeonbong@gmail.com

Comment: I cant even get it to work using postman, in postman i am using content -type "application - json" , using the post method, and using key, value as title and foo respectively in form data. There is some issue with my spring controller, the other post methods work fine.

Comment: @user3809938 my fault. I haven't focused on your Spring backend. I've updated my Spring backend. The key change is the parameter type. please check it out.

Comment: is there a variable declaration after the map<string string>, even after putting a variable i get same error?

Comment: @user3809938 would you mind sharing your project with me so that I can check it out locally. The above code works on my machine.